# incomplete implementation why i cant solve this issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

Plz anyone tell me how to solve incomplete implementation warning :

> Semantic Issue-Incomplete implementation) @interface SecondController
>   () @end
>
> @implementation SecondController

EDIT:

```
 #import "SecondController.h" 

 @interface SecondController ()
 @end 

 @implementation SecondController

 @synthesize webv;
   - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
       self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
       if (self) {

       }
        return self;
    }  
   -(void)setWebv:(WebView *)webview {
       [[webview mainFrame] loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.yahoo.com"]]];
       [self alertfunction];
     }
 @end
```

Comment: please show full .h and .m files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> incomplete implementation warning Semantic Issue-Incomplete
>   implementation

This is seen when you declare methods in interface and doesn't define them in implementation file.

*Number of argument mismatch is one of the silly mistake.*

Comment: Keep it up Sir,you are the one of the finest man ever seen for iOS in India.. Good Luck

Comment: @BuntyMadan: Nothing like that. I am still learning. Yes  I guess I have 17K points in SO, but I know many senior Pro's having 14yrs exp in cocoa, but not in SO. And I am not an iOS developer. :)

Comment: whatever i share what i think. newbie like me getting lots for motivation from people like you thanks

Comment: @BuntyMadan: I suggest to follow, H2CO3, bbum, viki, josh cashwell, rmaddy, rmartin, daveDeLong, rob mayoff and many more. I learnt from them and still learning.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for sharing as we learning form your blog but today got some advice for only me feeling good.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without your code please check this.

```
In the Case of `Semantic Issue - Incomplete implementation`
```

Xcode will tell you what you are missing.
Steps : `Choose View > Navigators > Show Issue Navigator`, 
then turn down all of the disclosure triangles:
Hope it will help you.

[image]

Comment: how to remove the webview in cocoa application

Comment: #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>
@interface SecondController : NSViewController
@property(nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet WebView *webv;
-(BOOL)networkalertfunction;

Comment: [self.WebView removeFromSuperview]; use this line to remove it.

Comment: WHY THIEF MASTER DELETED MY POST

Comment: see i posted my question  2 weeks back but now it was showing ur post deleted